# How do replace some of the text in an attribute in all classes? (pure js)

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a working example in jquery, but there are compatibility issues, so I want to rewrite this in pure javascript. How do I do this correctly?

```
$(setInterval(
    function(){
        $('.swiper-zoom-container > img').each(function(){
    var srcset = $(this).attr('srcset');;
    $(this).attr('srcset', srcset.replace('s=1000x700','s=4000x4000'));
  });
    }, 300
));
```

My attempt was like that, but it's not a workable option:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.swiper-zoom-container > img');

setInterval(function() {
  elements.srcset = elements.srcset.replace('s=1000x700','s=4000x4000');
}, 300);
```

Comment: Where's the `each`? `elements` is a `NodeList`, which does not have a `srcset` property. It does have a `forEach` method though...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Does this work?
`elements.forEach(el => el.srcset.replace('s=1000x700','s=4000x4000');)`

Comment: Alas, the proposed option does not work.
https://jsfiddle.net/kaus0t17/1/

Comment: fixed and added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.swiper-zoom-container > img');

setInterval(function() {
  elements.forEach(el => el.srcset = el.srcset.replace('s=1000x700','s=4000x4000'));
}, 300);
```